# AngularJS: Stay Put directive; $watch element attr change

Tags: angularjs, attributes, element, directive, watch

I've been looking everywhere for a way to $watch a dom element's attributes for change within a directive. Everywhere I go, it says to do something similar to this:

```
/* Directive adjusts 'top' attr of element with a 
   position:absolute when element resizes,
   retaining it's position on the page */

.directive('stayPut', function() {
   var linker = function (scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch(function () { return element.height(); },
         function (newHeight, oldHeight) {
            var deltaHeight = newHeight - oldHeight;

            element.css('top',
               (parseInt(element.css('top') +
               deltaHeight)                 +
               'px');
         }, true
      );
   };

   return {
      link: linker,
      restrict: 'A'
   }
});
```

I can't get this to work for me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have to inform angular when the element resizes.

```
.directive('stayPut', function() {
   var linker = function (scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch(function () { return element.height(); },
         function (newHeight, oldHeight) {
            var deltaHeight = newHeight - oldHeight;

            element.css('top',
               (parseInt(element.css('top') +
               deltaHeight)                 +
               'px');

            element.on( "resize", function() {
               scope.apply();
            }); 
         }, true
      );
   };

   return {
      link: linker,
      restrict: 'A'
   }
});
```

I've not the time to try it yself. So it is just a hint.